# Python 3.7 doesn't print neither from command line nor from pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, pycharm

I have a windows 10 laptop with Python 3.7 installed together with modules numpy and scipy. However, when I try to execute the following code from command line or in pycharm I don't get any output. Also a simple print statement in an empty .py file with no import of modules doesn't work.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
def CatvsDogClassifier():
  print("Loading images for training ")
  X = np.zeros(750000, 80000)
  Fd = open("C:\\Users\Gianluca\Desktop\kittens\dataset\\training_set\dogs", "r")
  Fc = open("C:\\Users\Gianluca\Desktop\kittens\dataset\\training_set\cats", "r")
  for line in Fd:
    i=1
    arr=np.zeros(500, 500, 3)
    image = 'C:\\Users\Gianluca\Desktop\kittens\dataset\\training_set\cats\\'+line
    arr = misc.imread(image)
    arr=np.reshape(750000,1)
    X = np.hstack((X[:, :i], arr, X[:, i:]))
    print (X)
if __name__ =="__main__":
  CatvsDogClassifier()
```

Comment: ...you can't just change your question after you got an answer that solves your issue... now the answer does not make any sense anymore.

Comment: This is the exact reason why you should make a mvce. Now the work of @hiroprotagonist was for nothing. Not nice

Comment: I apologize, but the modifications have not solved my issue. They were done just to avoid answers about the uncorrectness of my code that is not the problem. As I already mentioned also a simple print in pycharm doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def __main__():
    CatvsDogClassifier()
```

this in itself does nothing (well, it defines a function but does not execute it).

you should do something like

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    CatvsDogClassifier()
```

to actually run your code (if your module is exectuted and not imported).

Comment: my mistake, nevertheless it doesn't work also fixing this issue, nothing is printed anyway.

Comment: does `if __name__ == '__main__': print('hello')` work? (works fine for me. pycharm and command-line). if in pycharm: are you sure you run the correct module?